# Sublime text 3 plugin issue 'Browser Refesh'

Tags: ubuntu, php, mysql, sublime-text-3

Are trying to use an plugin that is named "Browser Refresh"(link below), have instaled the plugin alog side "package manager" for st3 but with no luck to use it. Have so far edited the requireded /preferences>package settings>browser refresh>keybinding - user/. When doing so to "Ctrl + Shift + r" nothing happens, when doing so to ctrl+s and try to save and refresh nothing happens but the `default ctrl+s for st3` does not save. Must use /file>save/ instead. That might be because st3 only allow one function per keybinding.

Additional information:
Did restart st3 after each remap.
Did try difrent hotkey combinations.
Loaded a file (both .php and .html) to xampp then opened it in st3.

```
"keys": ["Ctrl + Shift + r"], "command": "browser_refresh", "args": {
    "auto_save": true,
    "delay": 1.0,
    "activate": true,
    "browsers" : ["chrome"]
}
```

Software info:
Ubuntu 18
google chrome
sublime text 3
package manager
browser refresh
xdotool from Ubuntu repository

[Browser Refresh at pacagecontrol.io](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Browser%20Refresh)

Please ask if any is unclear.
Appreciating any response.

Update:
Console gives no message when ctrl+shift+r is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this plugin to work (v2.0.4 for Sublime 3) by using it in the following way:

1. Open the file you are editing (i. e. something.html) in Chrome.
2. Alt+tab back to Sublime's window.
3. Edit file and press Ctrl+Shift+r (Chrome's window should come to the front and refresh).
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3.

I use the default key bindings settings indicated here https://github.com/gcollazo/BrowserRefresh-Sublime#2-configure-key-bindings

If you have several tabs opened the file you are editing has to be in the active tab for it to be refreshed.

If Chrome's window is minimized the plugin doesn't work (hence why I suggest switching windows with Alt+tab).

Comment: Thank you for responce.I did find https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload i also struggled with but after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886011/how-do-i-install-livereload-on-sublime-text-3 it now works. This does not bring the browser to the foregroud wich i kinda like when i learn heavily for small chances and a lot of refreshes.

Comment: While using Browser Refresh did you check Chrome's window was not minimized and the file you were editing was open in the browser's active tab?

Comment: The file was opened in an already crowded browser window. The window was open and in the background while viewing the editor. Did restart the browser but never only opened the file in a new window. Guess that was the reason it dident want to work.